# Enumerator code keeps returning Tuple errors when no Tuples are present

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tuples, enumerators

This is the following code I decided to practice with using enumerators (if you get the references you get a cookie). I am constantly getting errors in the do/while loop referring to tuples when I have none set. While I could use them I am intending to expand on this same code later on so tuples would only make the process messier in the long run in my opinion.

```
using System;

namespace Enumerator
{
class Program
{


    public enum color { Red, White, Green, Blue };
    public enum system { ZERO, LAMBDA, PSYCHOMU, _00 };
    public enum weapon { Beam_Rifle, _130mm_cannon, Flying_Bits, Beam_Cannon }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Choose configuaration of color, system, and weaponry for your mobile suit.");
        Console.WriteLine("You may only choose 1 system as having multiples on one frame will cause a malfunction.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        string color = enum Color;
        string system = enum System;
        string weapon = enum Weapon;


         do 
            {   
                color = Console.WriteLine(enum color);
                switch (color, system, weapon)

                case "Red":
                Console.WriteLine("Red");
                break;

                case "White":
                Console.WriteLine("White");
                break;

                case "Green":
                Console.WriteLine("Green");
                break;

                case "Blue":
                Console.WriteLine("Blue");
                break;

                default:
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid choice.");
                break;
               } while (color = Console.WriteLine(enum color));
            }
             Console.WriteLine();
             Console.ReadLine();



}
}
}
```

Comment: `(color, system, weapon)` is a tuple...

Comment: what do you intend to mean by `string color = enum Color;` ? or `Console.WriteLine(enum color);` - especially since you have `color = Console.WriteLine(...`), but that method returns `void`? this... isn't valid code at all - can you tell me what that is *meant* to mean? then we can probably tell you what you're doing wrong

Comment: I was intending the loop to break once a color was chosen, since I had not used enumerators before I was unsure of what to call it.

Comment: a `switch` takes *one* input; I don't know what you *intend* to do with all 3, but it looks like you're mostly interested in the color at this point, is that right? I *think* your entire loop can be just: `color color = default(color);` and `while(!Enum.TryParse<color>(Console.ReadLine(), true, out color)) { }` ?

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I was intending only color for now. It feels weird asking for help on things i am learning, used to doing it myself but this was actually driving me up the wall.

Comment: Mickel to be honest, it is really hard to answer your question - the code is *so far* from compiling that I can't figure out which thing it is that you're stuck on - because *virtually none of it* compiles. Maybe you should pare the code back a bit to the first bit that compiles "before", but stops working "after"...

Comment: The first error occurs at string color = enum color;

Comment: Indeed, I'm not surprised; that just... isn't C#. If you can explain what *you* think that line means, I might be able to tell you what it should be, but...  I can't infer your intent from that line.